# How to do animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

i want to learn animation in android. Could anyone please recommend a good book to learn this from. 
Is there any other way of learning the same?

thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 For wanting to learn it by yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a good tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) on Flip 3D animation in Android..

[Android 3D Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx). Just like iphone gallery.

Comment: It also provides [CoverFlowWidget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)..

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tutorials on animations:

[Tweening](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343)

[Slide in and slide out](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)

[Rotating tutorial](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/)